# Does Naruto still have Six Paths Sage Mode?

Tags: naruto

Yeah, I know there are lots of questions about this topic but not quite enough.
Can anyone tell me What happened to Naruto's Six Paths Sage Mode?
Does he still have Six Paths Sage Mode?
Somewhere, I don't remember where, I read that they sealed it. Is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He does have sage mode afterwards, because he uses it in the final fight in Boruto: The Movie. Here's what Narutopedia has to say about it:

> The one consistent hallmark of Six Paths Sage Mode are Naruto's eyes: his eyes are yellow, his pupils are a cross of vertical fox-slits with horizontal toad-slats, and there is no pigmentation around his eyes that would otherwise signify standard Sage Mode.

[image]

The confusion arises from the different types and inconsistencies. There are different modes of sage of six paths: non-cloak, cloak, and ashura kurama mode.

And the way he looks in Shippuden and the Boruto movie are different. For example, in Boruto, he doesn't seem to possess truth seeking balls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Naruto still has a Six Paths Sage Mode anymore, I will offer an argument for the same.

Naruto may still have residual chakra and power techniques left from when he was in Six Paths Sage Mode from when he was in the fight with Madara.

I don't think Naruto's eyes are really a hallmark of the Six Paths Sage Mode because he was so twice before in the manga, once when he was in his fight with Pain and another time when he was in his fight with Obito and they figured out only nature-chakra worked on him.

My greatest argument for why he does not still possess it is the absence of "Truth-Seeking Ball"s, regardless of who it was, Obito, Madara, Naruto and the Six Paths Sage himself all had these orbs when they were in the mode. And to be in the Six Paths Sage Mode one would need to have chakra from all the tailed-beasts, what Naruto had in the fight with Madara was given to him by the Jinchuriki's and it wasn't their entire chakra just a part of it, so it enabled him to go into Six Paths Sage Mode for the fight against Madara and Kaguya.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that Naruto still owns it. These special eyes first appears after naruto got the sage power by the RS. The truth-seeking balls are a combination of all chakra natures, that only persons with the six paths power can create that's true, but they don't have too. Why naruto chooses not to in boruto the movie is not clear but sure he still can.

Answer (score 0):

Naruto doesn't possesses Truth Seeking orbs. So, there's no chance he can have sage of six paths sage mode. Also, Naruto wasn't able to use the six paths sage mode against Toneri while fighting on Moon.

Answer (score 0):

Naruto still has access to the mode. Just like he was able to send chakra to the Shinobi alliance periodically, he can still access their chakra. I dont think he has need of it right now. It's like bringing out a hammer to kill an ant.

Answer (score -2):

Wrong. He still has it because of the eyes.

It is also stated that once a user uses up the truth seeker orbs, they cannot create more, which means he would still have sage of six paths mode just without the truth seeker orbs. Same thing that happened with Madara.